# What is this "Nor"?

Tags: negation, neither-nor, or-nor

> And I saw Tityos, son of glorious Gaea, lying on the ground. Over nine roods he stretched, and two vultures sat, one on either side, and tore his liver, plunging their beaks into his bowels, **nor** could he beat them off with his hands.
>
> — *The Odyssey*

This *nor* is not like *not . . . either*.

This *nor* is similar to *never could he beat them off. . . .*

Is this correct? Is this an archaic use?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It may be a little archaic, but it's perfectly comprehensible.  Unlike the other respondents, I do not believe an implied previous phrase is required; it is simply *and he could not beat them off...* together with the rule that `*and not =nor*' (and possibly a reluctance to have too many *ands* in a sentence).

The Oxford English Dictionary agrees:

> ***nor***
>
> ...
>
> **5. Following upon an affirmative clause, or in continuative narration, with the force of *neither* or *and…not.***
>
> 1523 Ld. Berners Froiss. I. cxxxv. 162, *I greatly desyre to se the kynge my maister, nor I wyll lye but one nyght in a place, tyll I come there.*
>
> a1578 Lindesay (Pitscottie) Chron. Scot. (S.T.S.) I. 26 *To mak hir purgatione that scho was frie of all misrewlle...nor gave na counsall thairto.*
>
> 1631 May tr. Barclay's Mirr. Mindes i. 39 *The whole coast is most sweetly verdant, ...nor hardly, is there ground any where more abundantly fruitfull.*
>
> 1667 Milton P.L. iii. 626 *A golden tiar Circl'd his Head, nor less his Locks behind...Lay waving round.*
>
> 1697 Dryden Virg. Georg. iii. 161 *His Age and Courage weigh: Nor those alone.*
>
> 1738 Johnson London 260 *Then shall thy friend, nor thou refuse his aid, ...forsake his Cambrian shade.*
>
> 1788 Trifler No. 22. 291 *The little creature cried and laid down, nor could all our beating raise it.*
>
> 1821 Byron Heaven & Earth iii. 673 *Away! nor weep!*
>
> 1871 R. Ellis tr. Catullus lxi. 205 *Come nor tarry to greet her.*
>
> 1875 Jowett Plato (ed. 2) I. 423 *Nor among the friends of Socrates must the jailer be forgotten.*

Comment: I believe this is the right answer, especially considering the Greek. It makes sense to directly translate *d'ouk* ("and not") as *nor* in literary English, and I have seen *nor* used to mean "and not" without any preceding negative, real or imagined", in (older) literary English.

Comment: I don't think it as as comprehensible as you hope. It is surely a stumbling block and not at all common in speech or writing. Just because there is a logical translation of 'and not' to 'nor', doesn't necessarily lead to it flowing well. I wouldn't say it is archaic or obsolete, just not common nowadays. 'Nor' itself (in 'neither...nor' is falling out of favor (very high register).

Comment: @Mitch: I have added the relevant definition from the Oxford English Dictionary and quotations illustrating this literary/older use. // Tim, I hope you're OK with my adding the definition and quotations from the OED supporting your answer.

Comment: @Cerberus: anyone who thinks the OED a better authority than myself can only applaud you. Nor can I object.

Comment: This feels like a Latinate influence - "neque" alone meant "and not", but a paired "neque...neque" meant "neither...nor".

Answer (score 21):

This way of using *nor* is indeed somewhat archaic.

Normally, *nor* requires that another negative has been employed somewhere previously. In your *Odyssey* quote, for example, we might imagine something like this:

> Two vultures sat, one on either side, and tore his liver, plunging their beaks into his bowels. He could not rise himself, nor could he beat them off with his hands.

However, in older texts (especially, in my experience, older translations of Greek texts), *nor* could sometimes ‘piggyback’ not only on an expressed negative, but also on anything that implies a negative *somewhere in the situation*.

In this case, the despondent impuissance of Tityos creates such a situation. There is no explicit negative, but it is easy to imagine that the situation as a whole functions as a kind of ‘abstract negative’ that *nor* can be used to emphasise. Simply using *not* would just make it a plain statement that these birds were tearing out his innards and he couldn’t get rid of them—but using *nor* emphasises that the birds did not stop, he did not like it, it was not good … the whole thing was, basically, *negative*.

Comment: +1 Although I find the implication that the "plain statement that they were ripping out his liver" would _not_ covey a very, very negative situation a bit disturbing. (To quote Monty Python: "Worse? How much worse can it possibly get?")

Comment: @oerkelens, it would describe a very negative situation, but it would not necessarily emphasise the negativity of the situation in the description itself: the extra _nor_ does that and draws a heavy black line under the unspoken negation in the previous phrase, as it were.

Comment: @oerkelens Well, they could be eating your liver AND your kidneys!

Comment: @WS2: that would be preferable, as removal of the kidneys would end the suffering (the liver grows back). And while they're eating, I doubt the pain would be significantly worse. Maybe I am thinking too practically. :|

Comment: This construction is also used in Coleridge's 'Rime of the Ancient Mariner': "Water, water, every where/Nor any drop to drink."

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Excellent example. It and the OED agree with Tim's answer below, nor do I think Janus is right in his supposition of an imagined negation.

Comment: @Cerb, I think you're right. There doesn't necessarily have to be any negation imagined—but there does have to be something that a negation can semantically form a stark contrast to, then. “He has red hair and blue eyes, nor does he have a beard”, for example, still does not work.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I am uncertain, nor will my intuition lead me with regard to your example. But I don't always see a stark contrast: I sometimes merely see the equivalent of *and not*. The following is the most recent example from the OED (2nd ed.). *The other persons of the Dialogue may be considered under two heads: 1 private friends; 2 the respondents in the argument. First there is Crito, who has been already introduced to us in the Euthydemus and the Crito; he is the equal in years of Socrates and stands in quite a different relation to him from his younger disciples.* ...

Comment: ... *He is a man of the world who is rich and prosperous (cp. the jest in the Euthydemus 304 C), the best friend of Socrates, who wants to know his last commands, in whose presence he talks to his family, and who performs the last duty of closing his eyes. It is observable too that, as in the Euthydemus, Crito shows no aptitude for philosophical discussions. **Nor among the friends of Socrates must the jailer be forgotten,** who seems to have been introduced by Plato in order to show the impression made by the extraordinary man on the common.*

Comment: @Cerb, that usage fits fine to me. Basically, I guess I’m saying _and not_ is not quite enough for a synonym: _not either_ or _consequently not_ are closer. In the Socratic case here, we basically have, “There is Friend A, there’s Friend B, and we must _not_ forget Friend C _either_”. _Nor_ does form a contrast to the preceding examples there.

Comment: @Jan: I see what you mean, but I'm not sure. The supposition of hypothetical words or phrases in linguistics can be quite useful and convincing, nor is it without danger. (I am guessing you would asterisk the preceding sentence? When it stands for *but not*, it is perhaps the farthest removed from your kind of negation.) Your explaining the Socratic *nor* based on the broader context seems convincing; but what if I tried to defend the bearded *nor* thus? *He has blue eyes, nor does he have a beard = he has no brown eyes, nor does he have a beard*. My intuition wants to agree with you, though.

Comment: So what I was saying is, can't we always imagine or reconstruct some contextual, implicit contrast for anything? I'm not sure what to think.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your concern over this but I do think it is an instance of a normal use of 'nor'.

'Tityos was unable to protect himself, nor was he capable of beating off his attackers', is what I think it is saying. It is just that in the original, the first condition is not stated in the negative. Hence 'nor' seems out of place. It is a bit like saying;

'I was helpless, nor could I beat off my attacker'.

It sounds strange, but not if you say;

'I had neither protection, nor the capacity to respond'.

I do think however you are right when you say it is an archaic use and I believe that a modern translation would deal with it differently.

Comment: Thank you for awarding me the 'correct answer', but I do think Janus has said exactly the same thing, perhaps more eloquently than I have.

Answer (score 2):

I would hesitate to say that the use of *nor* here is archaic, but it does strike me as being uncommon today. In the context of the quote from *The Odyssey* -- and without seeing or understanding the original text -- I would probably render it as "..., and what is more, he could not beat them off".

Answer (score 0):

In this case "nor" means something akin to "and...not". Today this might be written as

> I saw Tityos, the son of glorious Gaea, lying on the ground, stretched across more than two acres. On each side of him sat a vulture, each plunging their beaks into his bowels and tearing at his liver, and he could not fight them off with his hands.

(Here I've taken this usage of "rood" to be as a measurement of area. If in this context "rood" is intended as a measurement of length, then "over nearly two hundred feet" should be substituted for "across more than two acres". Still a big boy, no matter how you measure him :-).

Share and enjoy.