# use of the conjunction "nor"

Tags: grammar

"She didn't get married nor had children". Is the use of "nor" correct? I know we can use "nor" without "neither" but I'm doubting in this case.

Comment: "... nor did she have children" would be valid syntax/semantics and reasonably idiomatic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use 'or' or 'nor' after a negative statement?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/should-i-use-or-or-nor-after-a-negative-statement)

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score -3):

> Is the use of "nor" correct?

No.

> I know we can use "nor" without "neither"

This is irrelevant.

**Not + or**

**Neither + nor**

"...<s>nor had</s> or **have** children."

Comment: But _She didn't get married. Nor did she have children_ would be fine.